# Loop through file timestamps, and if it equals to today's date, copy file

Tags: datetime, batch-file, cmd

Good Day All

I have a bunch of SQL files in a folder. Now I would like to loop through each file and get the timestamp of the file. If the timestamp mathes the current date, then I want to copy that file to a new location.

Here is the directory structure of the files:

```
c:\MFA\MFA_timestamp\MFA_timestamp.sql
```

and example of a file would be:

```
c:\MFA\MFA_20131008\MFA_20131008.sql
```

So here is the code I have so far, but its is not right...

```
set currentDate=%date%

FOR /R c:\MFA\ %%G IN (*.sql) DO SET %%G=%file%

FOR %%f IN (%file%) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf
IF %filedatetime:~0, 10% == %currentDate% goto same

goto notsame

:same
copy %file% c:\NEWLOCATION

goto next

:notsame

goto end

:next
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "currentDate=%date:~0,10%"
    for %%g in ("c:\mfa\*.sql") do (
     set "fileDate=%%~tg"
     set "fileDate=!fileDate:~0,10!"
     if "!fileDate!"=="%currentDate%" (
        copy "%%~fg" "c:\newLocation"
     )
    )
```

For each .sql file in the indicated folder, if the file date (10 first characters, i'm assuming the date in some mm/dd/yyyy variation) is equal to the current date (same amount of characters), copy the file to new directory

EDITED - It seems an 2008 server installation gives problems with delayedexpansion. Under the same asumption (from data in OP original question), that the date is in some mm/dd/yyyy variation, and since the file date in filedatetime is returned (as far as i know) in the same format in the `%date%` variable, this "should" work (i hope, the previous code also "should" work) without delayedexpansion

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f %%d in ("%date%") do for %%a in ("c:\mfa\*.sql") do for /f %%b in ("%%~ta") do (
        if "%%b"=="%%d" copy "%%~fa" "c:\newLocation"
    )

    endlocal
```

It takes the first token of the data returned by '%date%' and for each file in the indicated set, take the first token in the file datetime field and check agains the splitted current date. If the two values are equal, the file is copied to target.

EDITED 2 - Well, it seems it does not work in the 2008 server. Next try. Also without delayed expansion. As far as the `%date%` variable returns the information in the same format that the file datetime (not sure if it can be different), and that in file datetime the date part appears before the time part, "maybe" this works.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=d:\descargas\_work\x"
    set "target=c:\newLocation"

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in (
        'cmd /q /d /c "for %%f in ("%source%\*.*") do echo(%%~tf^|%%~ff"^|findstr /l /i /b /c:"%date%"'
    ) do (
        echo copy "%%a" "%target%"
    )
```

Comment: Great Stuff. Exactly what I need. Thank you so much. What does the following characters do: ~ % and %% ?

Comment: @DextrousDave: `%%~tg` is the time of the file referenced by `for` variable g, `%%~fg` is the full path of the file referenced by g. See `for /?` for a complete reference.

Comment: Hi MC ND. One more problem. I used this code on my local PC, which works fine(Win 7). Now I tried this on a Windows Server 2008,  but it is not working. I think it has something to do with the parsing of !filedate!. When I echo !filedate! on my local PC, it shows the date. However, when I echo !filedate! on the Windows 2008 server, the output shows: ECHO is off. I did try remove the @echo off but then the messages changes to "ECHO is on". What is wrong with the filedate variable on the windows 2008 server?

Comment: @DextrousDave, test the new code. If this does not work on your 2008, then the problem is not delayedexpansion.

Comment: thanks, but still does not work. When removing echo off, I can only see the %date% value returned, not the date value of the file(%%b)...

Comment: @DextrousDave, then, delayedexpansion is not the problem, as there are no variables set in the second code. It seems more a problem with extensions been disabled. Please, try to run your batch file as `cmd /e:on /c "theBatchFile.cmd"` to ask for extensions enabled on cmd instance.

Comment: Nope still does not work. Keeps saying ECHO is off. Any other way we can make this work?

Comment: @DextrousDave, What code are you trying? The second code in the answer does not include any `echo` command to obtain a `echo off`

Comment: Yes the echo is off i got with the first script. I also tried the second one, but nothing happens - does not copy anything...even though the timestamps match

Comment: @DextrousDave, when you run a `dir` command, what is format of the datetime stamp of the files in your 2008?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, if I understand what you need to do:

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"

for /r "c:\mfa" %%a in (MFA_%datestamp%.sql) do copy "%%a" "d:\target\folder"
```

Comment: Hi foxidrive. Thank, this works but not exactly as I want.You are mathcing the current date and the date contained in the filename. I want to match the current date with the timestamp of the file, not the  date contained in the filename.